# How to get SessionId Drupal Login from C#

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, drupal

I have proplem with Drupal Login Authentication , i have make an function send POST DATA to Drupal Login Page but can't login . I want to login and get Session Id and Session Value from Drupal for use REST Server API

Anyone can suggest some trick for that ?

Comment: You've told us what you want to do, but where are you actually stuck? Show us what you've attempted, and why it's failing. Please be as specific as possible. It appears to me to be as simple as making a regular POST request and storing the cookies from the response.

Comment: Thank you for reply , i've try to make POST Request from my app to Drupal site but can't login....

Comment: Added my example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found method , sorry , i just forget to create endpoint for drupal :D